# Regexp Query in Lucene

Tags: java, regex, lucene

I am working with lucene search, I am having list of names like

```
1) CITY OF CAIRO

2) CALICUT OFFICIAL BRANCH

3) CAIRO BRANCH OFFICE
```

If the user types **"CO"**, It have to bring the names that start with **"C"** and second word should start with **"O"**, It should return 1st name(**CITY OF CAIRO**) and 2nd name (**CALICUT OFFICIAL BRANCH**). The 3rd name(**CAIRO BRANCH OFFICE**) name **should not be returned**, As it is not having the **second word started with "O"**. I am using the RegexpQuery query. It is listing all the above 3 names which is wrong.

```
RegexpQuery dynamicRegEx3 = new RegexpQuery(new Term("name", "C.* O.*"));
```

What is the way to achieve this ?

Printed query is :::: **name:/C.* O.*/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is greedy, use this instead:

```
RegexpQuery dynamicRegEx3 = new RegexpQuery(new Term("name", "C[^ ]* O.*"));
```

`[^ ]` stands for any character that is not a space.

Comment: Still lucene prints all the three names,It should return the names that matchs, First word should start with "C" and second word should start with "O". Other names should be omitted.

Comment: Returns zero results.

Comment: Are those shorthands supported by lucene regex? Also try something like `^C[^ ]* O.*`

Comment: @Muthu: I can't test it here, but try to change `\\S` by `[^ ]`

Comment: @M42 Yeah. Great. It works, May I know the meaning of the symbol [^ ]

Comment: @M42 What are all the Symbol are supported and what is meaning of it, Is there any documentation for these symbols.

Comment: @Muthu: `[^ ]` means any character other than space. Look at http://www.regular-expressions.info but I don't know the which ones are supported by lucene.

Comment: Lucene supported regex syntax can be seen in the documentation of [the Lucene Regexp class](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html).  No reluctant matching, but negated character classes are fine.